# Add Button Value To Input Field On Click

Tags: html

I need to add the button value to a form input field when the button is clicked.

Rookie mistake, I had a working version of this but I replaced the html file by accident. I can't remember how I did it. I know it was not JS it was an OnClick function on the html file

```
<input id="userInput1" value="0">

<button id="p1"  value= "0" class="userbutton w-button" onclick="userinput1.display.value, RunGame()">0</button>


I expect it to add the button value to the input field.
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time though you might want to show some effort first. Also, you'll need to re-add your `runGame()` declaration. Removed for the sake of the working example,

eg; `onclick="setInputValue(this.innerHTML);runGame()"`

Cheers

```js
setInputValue = (val) => {

  document.getElementById('userInput1').value = val;

}
```

```html
<input id="userInput1" value="0">

<br/><br/>
<button id="p1" value="5" 
        class="userbutton w-button"
        onclick="setInputValue(this.innerHTML)">From HTML content</button>
        
<br/><br/>
or to get it from the value attribute;
<br/><br/>

<button id="p1" value="From the Value Attribute" 
        class="userbutton w-button"
        onclick="setInputValue(this.value)">From Attribute</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this way...

```html
<input id="userInput1" value="0">

<button id="p1"  value= "5" class="userbutton w-button" onclick="document.getElementById('userInput1').value = this.value; RunGame();">5</button>
```

And please define RunGame().